# Proxy object/reference getters vs setters?

Tags: c++, proxy, getter-setter, proxy-classes

When I am designing a generic class, I am often in dilemma between the following design choices:

```
template<class T>
class ClassWithSetter {
 public:
  T x() const; // getter/accessor for x
  void set_x(const T& x);
  ...
};
// vs
template<class T>
class ClassWithProxy {
  struct Proxy {
    Proxy(ClassWithProxy& c /*, (more args) */);
    Proxy& operator=(const T& x);  // allow conversion from T
    operator T() const;  // allow conversion to T
    // we disallow taking the address of the reference/proxy (see reasons below)
    T* operator&() = delete;
    T* operator&() const = delete;
    // more operators to delegate to T?
   private:
    ClassWithProxy& c_;
  };
 public:
  T x() const; // getter
  Proxy x();  // this is a generalization of: T& x();
  // no setter, since x() returns a reference through which x can be changed
  ...
};
```

Notes:

- the reason why I return `T` instead of `const T&` in `x()` and `operator T()` is because a reference to `x` might not be available from within the class if `x` is stored only *implicitly* (e.g. suppose `T = std::set<int>` but `x_` of type `T` is stored as `std::vector<int>`)
- suppose caching of Proxy objects and/or `x` is *not* allowed

I am wondering what would be some scenarios in which one would prefer one approach versus the other, esp. in terms of:

- extensibility / generality
- efficiency
- developer's effort
- user's effort

?

You can assume that the compiler is smart enough to apply NRVO and fully inlines all the methods.

**Current personal observations:**

(This part is not relevant for answering the question; it just serves as a motivation and illustrates that sometimes one approach is better than the other.)

One particular scenario in which the setter approach is problematic is as follows. Suppose you're implementing a container class with the following semantics:

- `MyContainer<T>&` (mutable, read-write) - allows modifying on both the container and its data
  implementation of the
- `MyContainer<const T>&` (mutable, read-only)  - allows modifying to the container but not its data
- `const MyContainer<T>` (immutable, read-write) - allows modifying the data but not the container
- `const MyContainer<const T>` (immutable, read-only) - no modifying to the container/data

where by "container modifications" I mean operations like adding/removing elements. If I implement this naively with a setter approach:

```
template<class T>
class MyContainer {
 public:
   void set(const T& value, size_t index) const {  // allow on const MyContainer&
     v_[index] = value;  // ooops,
     // what if the container is read-only (i.e., MyContainer<const T>)?
   }
   void add(const T& value);  // disallow on const MyContainer&
   ...
 private:
  mutable std::vector<T> v_;
};
```

The problem could be mitigated by introducing a lot of boilerplate code that relies on SFINAE (e.g. by deriving from a specialized template helper which implements both versions of `set()`). However, a bigger problem is that this *brakes the common interface*, as we need to either:

- ensure that calling set() on an read-only container is a compile error
- provide a different semantics for the set() method for read-only containers

On the other hand, while the Proxy-based approach works neatly:

```
template<class T>
class MyContainer {
   typedef T& Proxy;
 public:
   Proxy get(const T& value, size_t index) const {  // allow on const MyContainer&
     return v_[index];  // here we don't even need a const_cast, thanks to overloading
   }
   ...
};
```

and the common interface and semantics is not broken.

One difficulty I see with the proxy approach is supporting the `Proxy::operator&()`
because there might be no object of type `T` stored / a reference to available (see notes above). For example, consider:

```
T* ptr = &x();
```

which cannot be supported unless `x_` is actually stored somewhere (either in the class itself or accessible through a (chain of) methods called on member variables), e.g.:

```
template<class T>
T& ClassWithProxy::Proxy::operator&() {
  return &c_.get_ref_to_x();
}
```

Does that mean that the proxy object references are actually superior when `T&` is available (i.e. `x_` is explicitly stored) as it allows for:

- batching/delaying updates (e.g. imagine the changes are propagated from the proxy class destructor)
- better control over caching
  ?

(In that case, the dilemma is between `void set_x(const T& value)` and `T& x()`.)

Edit: I changed the typos in constness of setters/accessors

Comment: I've read this a couple of times and I am still not following what you're saying or asking. At high level it seems you want a class with a fixed internal type but whose interface is defined by the template type? Except that the class is going to be 'generic' aside from the fixed internal representation?

Comment: Suppose the class is some non-trivial wrapper/container and it should be able to store any type T. By interface I only mean "it should have a way of setting the stored object of type T". The inner type is not fixed (it is dependent on the type T), and the storage mechanism / the way how you get T from whatever you use is known at compile time. As an example, suppose T corresponds to some image type and the way you're actually storing it is different (perhaps it's compressed?), so you need a proxy, whenever you use a setter/proxy it uncompresses, modifies and re-compresses the image.

Comment: A `std::vector<T>` implies `const` on the container applies to the elements, as it "owns" its elements.  So storing your `std::vector<T>` without `mutable` is an error if those are the semantics you want.  In addition, I think your semantics are in error: you shouldn't use `const` that way.  `const_container_class` and `container_class` are better than `const container_class`.  Second, proxy should forward through set/get methods if you don't want to break encapsulation anyhow.

Comment: Why would set be allowed on a const reference? If someone uses your class and expects const to prevent setting, they could get unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Yakk: I made the vector mutable, to make the intention more clear.

@Straw1239: I want a semantics that is kind of similar to unique_ptr / smart_ptr; observe that even though you cannot reset (reassign) such a pointer via the const reference, you can still modify the pointed values (unless it's <const T>).

Btw, the question is not about this specific examples, it's about the design choice of having `void set_x(const T& x)` vs `T& get()` (or `Proxy` as a return type in general) as the way to encapsulate modifications to `x`.

Comment: @leden The semantics (regarding constness) of the two options you give are totally different, so there is no useful comparison to be made.

Comment: @leden I don't like using const in a way which allows any modification of the object. Code shouldn't have to worry about anything changing when passing a const reference to an object to a function. If you want a container which is itself unmodifiable but allows modification of it's elements, const is probably not the right way to do it.

Comment: @Straw1239: I apologize, the typos in constness of `x()`/ `set_x()` were accidental. Now it's what I primarily meant.

Comment: @leden smart pointers are pointer types.  `shared_ptr` have data that multiple pointers can refer to, and `unique_ptr` blocks multiple pointers referring to the same type.  In both cases, copy assignment and construction does not cause data duplication.  Do you block copy assignment and construction in your class?  That changes things.

Comment: @Yakk: You can assume that both the outer class and type `T` have both copy and move constructors and assignment operators. Moreover, I'm mostly interested in the cases where `T` is *not* a pointer type.

Comment: You have something following pointer semantics (`const` means pointer-to-data is `const`, but pointed-to-data is not `const`) in which copy construction/assignment causes copy-of-data.  This is distinct semantics than a smart pointer.  Which means that your semantics are not pointer-like, they are a hybrid of pointer-like and value-like.  This leads to problems, like the fact that your copy constructor has write-access to the right hand side.  I have found such designs ... problematic.  Good luck if you go down that route.

Comment: @Yakk: Thanks, I understand your concerns. I will reconsider this design. But for now let's not worry about this specific example. I think the discussion has gone off-topic... Btw, I though your question about copy assignment/construction is related to the general case (any class with a proxy/reference getter).

Answer (score 1):

Like most design dilemmas, I think this depends on the situation. Overall, I would prefer the getters and setters pattern, as it is simpler to code (No need for a proxy class for every field), simpler to understand by another person (looking at your code), and more explicit in certain circumstances. However, there are situations where proxy classes can simplify user experience and hide implementation details. A few examples:

If your container is some sort of associative array, you might overload operator[] for getting and setting the value for a particular key. However, if a key hasn't been defined, you might need a special operation for adding it. Here a proxy class would probably be the most convenient solution, as it can handle = assignment in different ways as necessary. However, this can mislead users: If this particular data structure has different times for adding vs setting, using a proxy makes this difficult to see, while using a set and put method set can make it clear the separate time used by each operation.

What if the container does some sort of compression on T and stores the compressed form? While you could use a proxy which did the compression/decompression whenever necessary, it would hide the cost associated with de/re compression from the user, and they might use it as if it were a simple assignment without heavy computation. By creating getter/setter methods with appropriate names, it can be made more apparent that they take significant computational effort.

Getters and setters also seem more extensible. Making a getter and setter for a new field is easy, while making a proxy which forwards the operations for every property would be an error-prone annoyance. What if you later need to extend your container class? With getters and setters, just make them virtual and override them in the subclass. For proxies, you might have to make a new proxy struct in each subclass. To avoid breaking encapsulation you probably should make your proxy struct use the superclasses's proxy struct to do some of the work, which could get quite confusing. With getters/setters, just call the super getter/setter.

Overall, getters and setters are easier to program, understand and change, and they can make visible the costs associated with an operation. So, in most situations, I would prefer them.

Comment: You don't really need a proxy class for every field - you have one proxy class templated over the field type, and then it's not even within the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think your ClassWithProxy interface is mixing wrappers/proxys and containers. For containers it is common to use accessors like

```
T& x();
const T& x() const;
```

just like the standard containers do, e.g. `std::vector::at()`. But normally access to members by reference breaks encapsulation. For containers it's a convinience and part of the design.

But you noted that a reference to `T` is not always available, so this will reduce the options to your ClassWithSetter interface, which should be a **wrapper** for `T` dealing with the way you store your type (while containers are dealing with the way you store objects). I would change the naming, to make clear, it might not be as efficient as a plain get/set.

```
T load() const;
void save(const T&);
```

or something more in context. Now it should be obvious, modifying `T` by using a proxy, again breaks encapsulation.

By the way, there is no reason not to use the wrapper inside of a container.

Answer (score 0):

I think that possibly part of the problem with your `set` implementation is that your idea of how a `const MyContainer<T>&` would behave is inconsistent with how standard containers behave and therefore would likely confuse future code maintainers. The normal container type for "constant container, mutable elements" is `const MyContainer<T*>&` where you add a level of indirection to clearly indicate your intention to users.

This is how the standard containers work, and if you utilize that mechanism you don't need the underlying container to be mutable nor the `set` function to be `const`.

All that said I slightly prefer the `set`/`get` approach because if a particular attribute only needs a `get` you don't have to write a `set` at all.

However I prefer not writing any direct access to members (like get/set or proxy) but instead providing a meaningfully named interface through which clients can access the class functionality. In a trivial example to show my meaning, instead of `set_foo(1); set_bar(2); generate_report();` prefer a direct interface like `generate_report(1, 2);` and avoid directly manipulating class attributes.